# Magento 2: System Configuration Error

Tags: magento2.2.6, system-configuration

I cannot open my System Configuration in Magento 2.2.6, I have forced it back to Developer mode, error below & all installed modules.

I'm starting to pull my hair out. It worked on one system, I moved to the cloud and now this.

```
    1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: id in /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php on line 65

Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined index: id in /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php on line 65
#0 /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure/Element/Iterator.php(65): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined index...', '/opt/bitnami/ng...', 65, Array)
#1 /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure.php(146): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Element\Iterator->setElements(Array, 'default')
#2 /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/generated/code/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Structure/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure->getTabs()
#3 /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/Structure.php(209): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Interceptor->getTabs()
#4 /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/generated/code/Magento/Config/Model/Config/Structure/Interceptor.php(76): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure->getFirstSection()
#5 /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/vendor/magento/module-config/Controller/Adminhtml/System/AbstractConfig.php(60): Magento\Config\Model\Config\Structure\Interceptor->getFirstSection()
#6 /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\AbstractConfig->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#7 /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#8 /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/vendor/magento/module-backend/App/Action/Plugin/Authentication.php(143): Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#9 /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\Backend\App\Action\Plugin\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#10 /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/generated/code/Magento/Config/Controller/Adminhtml/System/Config/Index/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)
#12 /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/FrontController.php(55): Magento\Config\Controller\Adminhtml\System\Config\Index\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#13 /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#14 /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
#15 /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#17 /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#19 /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(257): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#20 /opt/bitnami/nginx/html/pub/index.php(37): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#21 {main}
```

Modules:

```
List of enabled modules:
    Magento_Store
    Magento_AdminNotification
    Magento_Directory
    Magento_Eav
    Magento_Theme
    Magento_Customer
    Magento_Backend
    Magento_Indexer
    Magento_Cms
    Magento_Catalog
    LitExtension_CartMigration
    LitExtension_Core
    Magento_Payment
    Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport
    Magento_Config
    Magento_Authorization
    Magento_Quote
    Magento_Rule
    Magento_Backup
    Magento_SalesSequence
    Magento_Bundle
    Magento_BundleImportExport
    Magento_CacheInvalidate
    Magento_Sales
    Magento_CatalogInventory
    Magento_Security
    Magento_CatalogImportExport
    Magento_Checkout
    Magento_Cron
    Magento_Msrp
    Magento_Search
    Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite
    Magento_Widget
    Amazon_Core
    Magento_CheckoutAgreements
    Amazon_Login
    Magento_CmsUrlRewrite
    Magento_User
    Magento_ConfigurableImportExport
    Magento_ConfigurableProduct
    Magento_ConfigurableProductSales
    Magento_Contact
    Magento_Cookie
    Magento_Email
    Magento_CurrencySymbol
    Magento_Vault
    Magento_Integration
    Magento_CustomerImportExport
    Magento_Deploy
    Magento_Developer
    Magento_Dhl
    Magento_Paypal
    Magento_Downloadable
    Magento_ImportExport
    Klarna_Core
    Magento_Newsletter
    Magento_EncryptionKey
    Magento_Fedex
    Magento_GiftMessage
    Magento_GoogleAdwords
    Magento_GoogleAnalytics
    Magento_Ui
    Magento_GroupedImportExport
    Magento_GroupedProduct
    Magento_DownloadableImportExport
    Afterpay_Afterpay
    Magento_InstantPurchase
    Magento_Analytics
    Magento_LayeredNavigation
    Magento_Marketplace
    Magento_MediaStorage
    Magento_CatalogRule
    Magento_Multishipping
    Magento_NewRelicReporting
    Magento_ProductAlert
    Magento_OfflinePayments
    Magento_SalesRule
    Magento_PageCache
    Magento_Authorizenet
    Magento_Braintree
    Magento_Persistent
    Magento_Reports
    Magento_ProductVideo
    Klarna_Ordermanagement
    Magento_WishlistAnalytics
    Mageplaza_Smtp
    Rokanthemes_BestsellerProduct
    Rokanthemes_Blog
    Rokanthemes_Brand
    Rokanthemes_Categorytab
    Rokanthemes_CustomMenu
    Rokanthemes_Featuredpro
    Rokanthemes_LayeredAjax
    Rokanthemes_MostviewedProduct
    Rokanthemes_Newproduct
    Rokanthemes_Onsaleproduct
    Rokanthemes_OpCheckout
    Rokanthemes_PriceCountdown
    Rokanthemes_ProductTab
    Rokanthemes_QuickView
    Rokanthemes_RokanBase
    Rokanthemes_SearchbyCat
    Rokanthemes_SlideBanner
    Rokanthemes_Superdeals
    Rokanthemes_Testimonials
    Rokanthemes_Themeoption
    Rokanthemes_VerticalMenu
    Temando_Shipping
    Vertex_Tax
    Webkul_AccordionFaq
    Webkul_GiftCard
    Webkul_Pos

    **List of disabled modules:**
    Goeasyship_Shipping
    Mageplaza_Core
```

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs if you try to add config settings (`system.xml`) to an non-existing config tab.

I guess it come from `Mageplaza_Smtp`, that tries to add config to Mageplaza config section and it fails because `Mageplaza_Core` is disabled.

Please enable `Mageplaza_Core` (or modify system.xml in `Mageplaza_Smtp`, to add config to another tag like "general")

Comment: I've actually removed Mageplaza_Core & Mageplaza_Smtp from the system..

Comment: @NoMansLand and error is still there after disabling both?

Comment: Yes, this is correct

Answer (score 0):

OK Steps to resolve (MagePlaza_Core was disabled & removed, MagePlaza_SMTP was disabled & removed)

But their code didnt class it as "disabled" and "forgot" to tell Magento.

SO what did I do? Edited: /app/etc/config.php

Removed Mageplaza_Core & Mageplaza_SMTP
Cleared Cache
Flushed the Cache
Deployed Static Content

Low & Behold here comes The Settings page!